# wordpress, как вызвать функцию через URL?

Tags: wordpress

Я хочу вызывать работу функции по конкретной URL
localhost http://localhost:8888/portal/?action=updateData

Как это правильно реализовать?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: tested
Description: tested
Version: 1.0
*/

use SDportal\controllers\MyCasesController;

add_shortcode('sdportal_login','sdportal_login');

function sdportal_login()
{
    $acc = new MyCasesController();

    return $acc->portal();

}
```

или мне мой GET параметр нужно ловить в `function sdportal_login()` и там уже вызывать метод с моего контроллера что мне нужен?

Comment: Прочитайте про REST API. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/